# for each output (sql) a different class

Tags: php, mysql

```
if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
    while ($list = $result->fetch_object()) {
        $titel = $list->titel;
        echo "<li class=\"wow fadeInLeft\">$titel </li> ";
    }    
    $result->close();
}
```

I have several rows in a table. Some rows need the fadeInleft class, the second row needs fadeInRight class, the third row fadeInleft, the fourth row fadeInRight etc.

What's the best way?

Answer (score 1):

You want different classes for odd/even. Try this -

```
$i = 1;
while ($list = $result->fetch_object()) {
    if($i %2 == 0) {
        $class = 'fadeInRight';
    } else {
        $class = 'fadeInLeft';
    }

    //Use $class in li
    echo "<li class='wow $class'>$titel</li>";

    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there is a better way, but

```
$check=True;
while ($list = $result->fetch_object()) {
     $titel = $list->titel;
     $cls=$check ? "fadeInRight" : "fadeInLeft"
     echo "<li class=\"wow $cls\">$titel </li> ";
     $check=!$check
}    
$result->close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a modulo. Like this:

```
$i = 1;
if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
    while ($list = $result->fetch_object()) {
        $titel = $list->titel;
        $class = ($i % 2 == 0) ? 'fadeInLeft' : 'fadeInRight';
        echo "<li class='wow $class'>$titel</li>";
    }
    $result->close();   
}
```

Or using bitwise:

```
$i = 1;
if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
    while ($list = $result->fetch_object()) {
        $titel = $list->titel;
        $class = ($i & 1) ? 'fadeInLeft' /*odd*/ : 'fadeInRight' /*even*/;
        echo "<li class='wow $class'>$titel</li>";
    }
    $result->close();   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Slightly shorter version of the solution by @paubo147 which removes the need for the extra variable and does the assignment at the same time as checking for the value.

```
$check=True;
while ($list = $result->fetch_object()) 
{
     $titel = $list->titel;
     echo "<li class=\"wow ".(($check=!$check) ? "fadeInRight" : "fadeInLeft")."\">$titel </li> ";
}    
$result->close();
```